# Capturing grid item click event in react-grid-layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to capture the grid item's click and cancel the drag event? I want to open a modal window when a grid item is clicked, but I can't figure out how to implement this. I'm capturing the click with `onClick`, but `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` don't prevent the mousedown event that starts the dragging process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done by passing a onMouseDown to a child div element.

```
<RGL ... >
  <div> // If you add onMouseDown here react-draggable will override it. You will have to use nested element to capture clicks
    <div onMouseDown={ e => e.stopPropagation() }>
      ...
    </div>
  <div>
</RGL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a workable solution by using `movementx` and `movementy` to see if there was actual real movement.

```
private onDrag = (
_layout: Layout[],
oldItem: Layout,
_newItem: Layout,
_placeholder: Layout,
e: MouseEvent,
_element: HTMLElement) => {
if (e.movementX !== 0 || e.movementY !== 0) {
  this.props.onWidgetDragStart(oldItem.i);
}  };
```

`onWidgetDragStart` fires an event that sets a variable (redux reducer:)

```
{
\[actionConstants.DASHBOARD.WIDGET_DRAGGING_STARTED\]: (
    state: DraftObject<DashboardsState>,
    action: Action<string>,
  ) => {
   state.isWidgetDragging = true;
   state.indexOfCurrentDraggedItem = action.payload;
 }
}
```

the click event then looks like this :

```
private onTitleClicked = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
if (this.props.indexOfCurrentDraggedItem === this.props.options.id) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.updatingIndexOfCurrentDraggedItem();
  return;
}

if (!this.props.isWidgetDragging && !this.state.editMode) {
  this.setState({
    editMode: true,
  });
}
{
\[actionConstants.DASHBOARD.WIDGET_DRAGGING_STARTED\]: (
state: DraftObject<DashboardsState>,
action: Action<string>,
) => {
  state.isWidgetDragging = true;
  state.indexOfCurrentDraggedItem = action.payload;
  },
};
```

where the `updatingIndexOfCurrentDraggedItem` action sets the `indexOfCurrentDraggedItem` to `null`
and `indexOfCurrentDraggedItem` is injected as a prop to my widget component.

Answer (score 0):

I was on a mobile browser, and so the react-grid-layout was eating the `onClick` event. Instead, I also listened for the `onTouchStart` listener, which worked.

```
<IconButton onTouchStart={() => onEditItem(id)} onClick={() => onEditItem(id)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by `creating key 'isDragging`' in LocalStorage, because this solution synchronously executed and you can make delay.

Also you can use `useForceUpdate` custom hook in tandem with `isDraggable` useRef variable. I have a large nesting and this method did not help me.